# Transfer byte-buffer with ENC28J60

Tags: arduino-uno, ethernet, web-server, data, buffer

How do I transfer a series of byte[256]-buffers to a server with an ENC28J60 Ethernet adapter? I get blocks of `uint8_t` from an Arducam camera module and I'd like to transfer them to a host. Does somebody have an idea how to solve that? I asked a previous question regarding that topic but now new issues arrived.

This is how the array is filled:

```
uint8_t temp = 0, temp_last = 0;
byte buf[256];
length = myCAM.read_fifo_length();
while (length--) {
  temp_last = temp;
  temp =  SPI.transfer(0x00);
  if ((temp == 0xD9) && (temp_last == 0xFF)) {
    buf[i++] = temp;
    is_header = false;
    i = 0;
  }
  if (is_header == true) {
    //Write image data to buffer if not full
    if (i < 256)
      buf[i++] = temp;
    else {
      i = 0;
      buf[i++] = temp;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What protocol does your "host" use?

Comment: UDP, too. But probably I'm bad at writingn a proper receiver. Do you have an advice how this could look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you are using the EtherCard library you can send a UDP packet with:

```
ether.sendUdp(packet_data, length, srcPort, hisip, dstPort );
```

Assuming you have already set up your source port and have the destination IP address and port in `hisip` and `dstPort`.

The prototype for the function is:

```
void sendUdp (char *data,uint8_t len,uint16_t sport, uint8_t *dip, uint16_t dport);
```

The example `udpClientSendOnly.ino` with the library shows you UDP sending in action.

Comment: Thank you, I already did that. But only trash arrives at the receiver-side.

Comment: How do you know it is trash? Have you examined the actual data you are getting from the camera to make sure that you are actually sending what you think you are sending?

Comment: Yes, when I look at my console on arduino-side I get eg the JFIF-header. But when I make a plain plot of the incoming data from UDP than I cannot find that certain header.

Comment: This is what I tried: ether.sendUdp(buf, 256, srcPort, hostip, dstPort);

Comment: And you are sure that `buf` contains that JFIF header at the point of sending?

Comment: Well, if I do it in another way, that means, I add the line ether.sendUdp(temp, 1, srcPort, hostip, dstPort); directly behind temp = SPI.transfer(0x00); I'd expect at least the header (which I could recognize) to arrive. But it doesn't.

Comment: What OS are you using to receive it?

Comment: Right now: Mac OS X, node-js UDP-Server. I can switch to linux, though.

Comment: OS X may be fine - not sure what tools are available. Use `tcpdump -s0 -X <portno>` (that's what I use on Linux) to look at the raw data as it arrives on the computer to see if it's the same as your program says it is.

Comment: pktap_filter_packet: pcap_add_if_info(en5, 1) failed: pcap_add_if_info: pcap_compile_nopcap() failed

Comment: Do it as root...?

Comment: Actually, I missed the word "port" from there too - `sudo tcpdump -s0 -X port <portno>`

Comment: 0x0000:  38c9 8624 db62 4c5e 0c90 9e16 0800 4500  8..$.bL^......E.
 0x0010:  001d 0000 4000 3f11 0a0e c0a8 583e c0a8  ....@.?.....X>..
 0x0020:  5833 10e1 0539 0009 b2ff 0500 0000 0000  X3...9..........
 0x0030:  0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000            ............

Comment: I need to check if that is equivalent to what I've sended.

Comment: Also the buffer is maybe to big with 256. I lowered it to 32 for debugging.

Comment: I found the header!!!! 0x0000:  38c9 8624 db62 4c5e 0c90 9e16 0800 4500  8..$.bL^......E.
 0x0010:  003c 0000 4000 3f11 09ef c0a8 583e c0a8  .<..@.?.....X>..
 0x0020:  5833 10e1 0539 0028 143d 04d8 ffe0 0010  X3...9.(.=......
 0x0030:  4a46 4946 0001 0101 0000 0000 0000 ffdb  JFIF............
 0x0040:  0043 0004 0303 0403 0304                 .C........

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64557/discussion-between-majenko-and-goetzmoritz).